# XCopy exclude list. Exclude by extension in folder

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I use XCopy with exclude list which looks like

.cs\
\Log\

and the XCopy command

SET exludedPaths=%cd%\Settings\excluded_paths.txt
SET projectDir=%cd%\MyFolder
SET outputDir=%cd%\Drops\
XCOPY /S %projectDir% %outputDir%\ /EXCLUDE:%exludedPaths%

All works fine, but I want to ignore xml-files from another one directory (only xml-files), something like this

.cs\
\Log\
\anotherdirectory\*.xml <-it doesn't work.

How I can specify the last line in excluded list or it isn't possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yep.Exclude does not support wildcards.

```
pushd cs\log\anotherdirectory
for /f %%f in (dir /b *.xml) do (
   echo %%~ff >> %exludedPaths%
)
popd
```

this should list all files in `anotherdirectory` into the excluded list